# What are the KPIs of DNS Management?

Tags: domain-name-system

I've just read an old RFP and one of the questions was along the lines of "List the top 3 KPIs of DNS management".

As a web developer, I have a working knowledge of DNS but no idea what would be considered a KPI of managing a collection of domain names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, and in no particular order:

At the management level:

- reliability of renewals process (**don't** allow your customers' domains to drop!)
- time to register domains from order
- change request response time (changing records, etc)

At the network level:

- response latency (you should answer quickly)
- response reliablity (you shoudn't drop any responses)
- distribution latency (how long for changes to be reflected in all authoritative servers)